# Is it possible to catch all errors in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app which is effectively a front-end to an SQL database. The connection to the database can be unreliable, so I've adopted the `pool` package to handle the connections. However, there are still some rare cases where the connection is lost and the connection pool cannot recover.

This can be solved by using `tryCatch` to handle such errors: if an error is thrown, I can handle it by restarting the connection. However, this would get very bloated very fast, having to duplicate this code every time I query the database.

Or, to keep my code DRY, I could create a wrapper around all the `DBI` functions (i.e. a function which calls `dbSendQuery()` within a `tryCatch` and handles any errors that pop out) but that would be a hassle.

The simplest solution, in my opinion, would be to have a function which catches all errors. I can then determine whether the error is relevant, refresh the connection, and then simply ask the user to try again. If any other type of error appears, I can display it to the user.

I've seen the `shiny::validate` and `::need` functions, but can't see how to use them or any sort of `observe*()`  method to solve this problem.

So, can this be done in an elegant way?